# How to mock some functions in a module with Jest

Tags: typescript, jestjs, mocking

I have a module that only contains named exports.
I'm trying to test just two of the functions from that module - the `cookieData` function & the `unauthenticate` function.
I want the `cookieData` to be mocked `unauthenticate` remain un-mocked.

Here is a simplified view of what my module looks like
**index.js**

```
const cookieData = () => {
    console.log('real cookieData fn hit')
}

const unauthenticate = () => {
    console.log('real unauthenticate fn hit')
    cookieData()
}

export { unauthenticate, cookieData }
```

I can successfully mock `cookieData`, if I call `cookieData` directly
 (This is just to test that I've mocked `cookieData` properly)
**unauthenticate.test.js**

```
import { cookieData, unauthenticate } from '../src';

jest.mock('../src', () => {
  const original = jest.requireActual('../src');
  return {
    ...original,
    cookieData: jest.fn(() => console.log('fake cookieData fn hit'))
  };
});

test('error will be thrown if there is no cookie to be cleared', () => {
  cookieData();
  // The correct message "fake cookieData fn hit" is logged to the console
});
```

But, when I go to call `unauthenticate` from the test instead, my mock suddenly stops working and the real functions get hit.

```
import { cookieData, unauthenticate } from '../src';

jest.mock('../src', () => {
  const original = jest.requireActual('../src');
  return {
    ...original,
    cookieData: jest.fn(() => console.log('fake cookieData fn hit'))
  };
});

test('error will be thrown if there is no cookie to be cleared', () => {
  unauthenticate();
  // The wrong messages are logged to the console
  // This logs out "real unauthenticate fn hit" then "real cookieData fn hit"
  // It SHOULD be "real unauthenticate fn hit" then "fake cookieData fn hit"
});
```

I can't understand why my mock stops working when I use the unmocked function.
I have also tried doing `import * as module from '../src'` and then just assigning an individual mock function to `module.cookieData` like this

```
module.cookieData = jest.fn(() => console.log('fake hit'));
```

But that does not work either. When I call `module.unathenticate()` it will still call the real methods.

Comment: Please include all file names and contents needed to reproduce the issue that you describe (all relevant source modules, tsconfig.json, package.json, etc.) needed for a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @jsejcksn I did

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73407853/how-to-mock-some-functions-in-a-module-with-jest?noredirect=1#comment129638473_73407853) You didn't. Be sure to read over the [article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) I linked: the details of your question don't meet that criteria.

Answer (score 0):

What if you add `__esModule: true,` and try with the same code?

```js
jest.mock('../src', () => {
  const original = jest.requireActual('../src');
  return {
    __esModule: true,
    ...original,
    cookieData: jest.fn(() => console.log('fake cookieData fn hit'))
  };
});
```

Basically this is how it is shown in the [documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions#mocking-partials)

Comment: It does not make a difference unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

The solution or work around was to modify how `cookieData` was used in the index file.

```
import * as module from './index';

const cookieData = () => {
    console.log('real cookieData fn hit')
}

const unauthenticate = () => {
    console.log('real unauthenticate fn hit')
    module.cookieData()
}

export { unauthenticate, cookieData }
```

Test file

```
import { cookieData, unauthenticate } from '../src';

jest.mock('../src', () => {
  const original = jest.requireActual('../src');
  return {
    ...original,
    cookieData: jest.fn(() => console.log('fake cookieData fn hit'))
  };
});

test('error will be thrown if there is no cookie to be cleared', () => {
  unauthenticate();
  // It logs out "real unauthenticate fn hit" then "fake cookieData fn hit"
});
```